# Why use 出し instead of 出す(N5 test multiple choice)

Tags: grammar

銀行へお金を(出し)に行きました
What is 出し　and why use it in this context?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please also explain how much of the rest of the sentence you understand, so it's easier for potential answerers to give helpful comments.

Comment: https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/48

Comment: Please learn the `stem + に + motion verb` pattern.